# What function does this series represent?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, power-series

A midterm I proctored recently showed that

$$ \cos(\sqrt{x}) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k x^k}{(2k)!}$$

The question asked what function this series represents.  It may represent cosine, but when plotted, the function is defined for $x<0$.

Here is my reasoning:

$\cos(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \implies \cos(\sqrt{x}) = \dfrac{e^{i\sqrt{x}}+e^{-i\sqrt{x}}}{2}  $

Now when $x<0$, $$\cos(\sqrt{x})=\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{|x|}}+e^{-\sqrt{|x|}}}{2}$$

Which, if I recall correctly, is $\cosh(\sqrt{|x|})$.

Maple seems to agree with me, so I am looking for some verification.

Comment: So write down the series for $\cosh x$ and compare.

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side is an entire function.  What happens on the left? The cosine function is even in the complex plane.  So the ambiguity of the square root is "eaten" and made well-defined by the cosine function.  So there is no problem.